# Graph API office365Move mails

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to move mails b/w different mailboxes in office365 using Microsoft graph API ?

I have tried moving mails inside the same mailbox (using token after getting admin consent) ,it's working
But how can i move the mail to other mailbox.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a supported scenario. You would need to forward the message to the target mailbox.

Comment: But while forwarding , the message details and headers are getting changed , Is there any way out to keep these details intact .